# Is there a good way to init an ObjC object on a background dispatch_queue?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, initializer

I have an ObjC class `RuleSet` that needs quite heavy initialization (parses a big JSON file, does lots of querying into several OS services, applies heuristics, and last, it builds a set of complicated `NSPredicates`, that can later be used for fast evaluation.

My program (except for this object) receives high-priority events from MacOS (EndpointSecurity framework) and has to respond to these within very narrow deadlines - based on the fast evaluation of my current `RuleSet` instance.

I handle those events in a special (highest priority) concurrent `dispatch_queue` I created.

However... if I receive some external trigger, to change my `RuleSet` - and I need to build the new `RuleSet` instance before applying it, I want the code creating it not to know about the internal structure of dispatch queues, and simply call

```
RuleSet *newRules = [[RuleSet alloc] initWithJSON:newJSONPath];
[myEventHandlingEngine setRuleSet:newRuleSet];
```

I'd like the RuleSet init to be able to somehow defer the work to another, low-priority serial dispatch_queue, maybe in parts. I don't mind blocking the caller until I'm done (this heavy init shouldn't take more than a second...). still, it's important that I do it on a queue that has lower priority - so that incoming events will be handled first.

Now I tried to write things like

```
- (instancetype) initWithJSON:newJSONPath:(NSString *)jsonFilePath
{
   dispatch_sync([RuleSet setupQueue], ^{
     if ( nil == (self = [super init]) ) {
        self = nil;
          return self;
     }

        // heavy work here
        });
    return self;
}
```

but that of course won't even compile because 'self' isn't a __block variable, and I'm not sure it can be...

Any advice on how to go about this?

Comment: While this slow building of the rule set is taking place, what should the handler for the high-priority events do in the absence of the completed rule set?

Comment: no absence. It keeps using the old RuleSet instance, until a new one is ready, and will atomically replace the old. Thanks to ARC and other Cocoa goodness - this works perfect and as simple as setting a property. As you can see in my stub "flow" code, I create new RuleSet, and then, I apply the new ruleset to the existing, and functioning "myEventHandlingEngine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using a dispatchGroup to handle that situation :

```
- (instancetype) initWithJSON:newJSONPath:(NSString *)jsonFilePath
{
    if ( nil == (self = [super init]) ) {
        self = nil; //This seems useless since self is already nil ?
        return self;
    }
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_async(group, [OITPreventionPolicy policySetupQueue], ^{
    
      // Execute your heavy work here

     });
     // Wait for the group to finish its work (you could replace 'forever' by a timeout)
     dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
     return self;
}
```

The call to `dispatch_group_wait` will block the thread in which the object is created (so it cannot be the main thread).

Comment: Actually, my main thread is not very important, and may be blocked at this time. The program is kind-of-but-not-exactly a "command-line tool" running as global daemon, whose main thread is used merely for initialization and communication with external processes. No UI in this thing, no networking, not anything you would use "main thread" for, regularly.

Comment: But I forgot... THANKS for the idea, it's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: change that to `if (!(self=[super init])) return nil;` or just `return nil` instead of pushing around nil

Comment: Why can't I block the main thread? does the OS have a problem with that? even for a low-level daemon process? What if I performed heavy computational thing on the main thread? is that forbidden too?

Comment: No, you cannot block the main thread, this is a constraint of the OS.  You should probably do the main job of your daemon in a secondary thread and only use the main thread when you must communicate with the AppKit API (windows, views and so on) or any other features requiring to do so.